# Profiles' access to Tab

Tags: profile

I am attempting to set the value of a Tab to be non-visible for all Profiles. I would like a quick way of seeing which Profiles have access to it (rather than going into each individual Profile to see). What is the easiest/quickest way to do that ? I don't think I can access the setting as a field in a report. I'm guessing the tab's setting is actually on a different object than the Profile object...? If so, I'm thinking I might be able to do it somehow on Workbench if I know the proper object...? Any ideas ?

Comment: have you tried looking through the metadata API document for clues?  That is where I would start.

Comment: I'm doing that now, thank you. I thought I would ask in here as well.

Comment: better read the docs first and then ask if anythng is unclear or not working as it should ;)